# Angular2 Auth Guard returning blank page with Observable.of(true)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using auth-guard to protect some of my routes, and at the same time of checking the authentication I'm getting a refresh token if the current token is expiring in less than 15 minutes.  My authenticated() method is returning an Observable.

The problem is when it goes to get the refresh token it's displaying a blank page, even though it's getting to the code of returning the Observable.of(true) (at least it's showing up in the console).  There's no error in the console.

If I don't get the refresh token (it's not time yet) then I also return the true Observable and it works fine.

In auth-guard:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.authenticated();
}
```

In auth.service:

```
authenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (isStillValid && currentTime.isAfter(refreshTime)) {
      return this._refreshAuthToken()
        .map((data) => {
          //****IT GETS HERE, BUT DISPLAYS BLANK ****
          return Observable.of(true);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          return Observable.of(false);
        });
     } else {
        if (!isStillValid) {
          //redirects to login
          return Observable.of(false);
        }
          return Observable.of(true);
        }
     }
}
```

_refreshAuthToken:

```
private _refreshAuthToken() : Observable<object> {
    return this._getAuthToken(body, headers)
        .catch(err =>  {
            return Observable.throw('Error');
        }) 
        .flatMap(data => {
            latestRefreshToken = data.refresh_token;
            body = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + latestRefreshToken;
            headers = new Headers('...');
            return this._getAuthToken(body, headers)
        })
}
```

_getAuthToken:

```
private _getAuthToken(body, headers) : Observable<object> {
    return this.http.post(this.restUrl + "/token", body, { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res.json())    
}
```

Comment: If you return an observable, I think you should `.flatMap`, otherwise you are returning `Observable<Observable<boolean>>`. Alternatively, only `return Observable.of(...)` in the `else` case, where you're not already in an observable.

Comment: your `_refreshAuthToken` method is returning observable so inside map you dont have to create a new observable just return true or false, Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function should return Observable of boolean but you return

```
Observable<Observable<boolean>>
```

If you do this in jsbin

```
Rx.Observable.of(1)
   .map(x=>Rx.Observable.of(true))
   .subscribe(x=>console.log(typeof x) // "object"
```

and

```
 Rx.Observable.of(1)
   .map(x=>true)
   .subscribe(x=>console.log(x) // "boolean"
```

So your code should:

```
 return this._refreshAuthToken()
    .map((data) => {
      //****IT GETS HERE, BUT DISPLAYS BLANK ****
      return true;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return Observable.of(false);
    });
```